# Chef-solo FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass when run with --no-fork option

Tags: chef-solo

When running chef-solo with --no-fork option it gives the error

FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Does any one know the reason for it . It works fine when --fork option.

Comment: Can you post the cookbook you are trying to run? Normally using fork prevents the chef client from leaking memory and makes it use a predictable amount of memory, so from this error alone we can't tell what is going wrong.

Comment: The error is not coming from the cookbooks I am using , it gives the error before it even reaches the first line in the recipes. NOt sure about the reason